# Algorithm to find maximum items that can be placed in the grid

Tags: algorithm

There is a grid of NXM points in a 2-D space. An item can be placed at a point (x,y) such that there must not be another item at (x+2,y-2) or (x-2,y-2) or (x-2,y+2) or (x+2,y+2). Moreover there are few points in the grid that are jammed i.e. an item can't be placed in these points.

So how to find maximum number of items that can be placed in the grid.

Comment: No , not a homework. Just a practice.

Comment: could you put an item at (10, 10) if (12, 8) and (8, 8) are free but (8, 12) and (12, 12) are taken?

Comment: no. consider n and m upto 1000

Comment: To avoid any confusion, I have edited the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal packing without these blocking points would be to place on columns

```
(a + 0), (a + 3), (a + 6), ..., (a + 3*n)
```

Wherever a block exists off of these columns, no improvement can be made. Where a block exists on the column, at (x, y), you can place points on (x+2, y-2) and (x-2, y-2). Therefore, look through all columns and try to place them to **minimize** the number of blocks on the column. (note that this said maximize before. I also had 3h. sleep last night)

Checking this can be done in n*m steps.

Comment: I guess this assumes that that is the optimal packing. You should probably check that.

Comment: Why optimal packing require items to be places on (a+3*n). Two items can be places adjacent also.

Comment: I am not sure but I guess some dynamic programming may work by linear traversal through all the points in the grid.

Comment: Never mind, I'm pretty sure this isn't optimal. It does feel like a DP solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's illustrative to consider the grid to be a torus, i.e. the sides "wrap-around" (top->bottom, left->right) so that you can ignore edge cases. When N and M are large this is a good approximation anyway.

On the torus, each point necessarily blocks two other points from existing, but you can overlap the exclusions, i.e. the one point's `(x+2, y-2)` is another point's `(x+2, y-2)`. So the maximum packing you can achieve is 1/2. This can be achieved by having alternating column stripes: 2 full columns, 2 empty columns, 2 full columns, etc.

I'll leave the corner cases (M not a multiple of 4).

On a grid that's not a torus then you have two considerations. First you can start the full columns directly up to the edges of the grid. Also you can fill the bottom two rows entirely ("bottom" being smallest y). So you can achieve packing slightly better than 1/2, but again as the dimensions approach infinity you still get 1/2.

Comment: There are points that are blocked so no item can be placed at these points. They may be isolated or may be in cluster.

Comment: Yeah, I addressed that. My clusters are columns. In other words, you have columns like this: `FF..FF..FF..FF` (`F` = column full of points, `.` = empty column (i.e. jammed locations)) The rows are all the same.

Comment: Alternatively you could go for horizontal stripes in a similar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the simpler 1d problem: given an array of length `n` with blocked cells, how many ways are there to populate it with ones such that if there is a 1 at `x`, there is no 1 at `x - 2` and `x + 2`.

Notice that this is a redundant condition: if we have a 1 at `x`, it's enough for no 1 to be at `x - 2` (if there's a 1 at `x + 2`, that one will break this reduced condition).

Let `dp[i, j] = number of ways to populate 1 .. i with points such that the last element is j`.

We have:

```
dp[i, 0] = dp[i - 1, 0] + dp[i - 1, 1] <- no 1 at i
dp[i, 1] = 2 * dp[i - 2, 0] <- we MUST have 0 at i - 2, but i - 1 can have whatever
=> if i is blocked dp[i, _] = dp[i - 1, _]
```

Example:

```
n = 3
brute force solutions:
000
010
100
001
110
011
=> 6
dp[0, 0] = 1 dp[0, 1] = 0
dp[1, 0] = 1 dp[1, 1] = 1
dp[2, 0] = 2 dp[2, 1] = 2
dp[3, 0] = 4 dp[3, 1] = 2
=> dp[3, 0] + dp[3, 1] = 6
```

The same can be used for your problem. Just notice that the condition can be reduced to **"there can be a point at (x, y) if there is no point at (x - 2, y - 2) and (x + 2, y - 2)"**. Then just iterate and fill in your dp matrix in `O(lines*columns)`.

Comment: I think you got the question wrong. Its not the number of ways but the maximum not items that can be placed in the grid.

Comment: @user1053930 - the same idea still stands, just use the max function instead of the summation and multiplication. It's not hard to adapt it if you have this much.